# SwiftUI: custom Pagination on TabView PageTabViewStyle not working properly

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm working on a custom Tabview Pagination and the below image is what I am trying to archive. The idea is when the textEditor if filled and user move to the next question ( tab index ), the Capsule will be filled with color.
[image]

However, my current code causing this weird UI
[image]

Here is The Progress View:

```
struct ProgressBarView: View {
@Binding var progress : [Progress]
let numberOfPages: Int
let currentIndex: Int

var columns: [GridItem] { [GridItem] (repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 30)), count: progress.count) }

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{ geometry in
        HStack{
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading){
                ForEach(0..<numberOfPages) { index in // 1
                  if shouldShowIndex(index) {

                      CapsuleView(currentIndex: currentIndex, index: index)
                      .id(index) // 4
                  }
                }
            }
//...
        }
    }
}

  func shouldShowIndex(_ index: Int) -> Bool {
    ((currentIndex - 1)...(currentIndex + 1)).contains(index)
  } 
}
```

The CapsuleView:

```
struct CapsuleView: View {
let currentIndex: Int
let index: Int

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill( currentIndex == index ? Color.blue : Color.clear).opacity(0.5)
    }
    .frame(height: 10)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
    )
}
```

}

and lastly in my Content View

```
TabView(selection: $currentIndex.animation()) {
                        ForEach(0..<progress.count, id: \.self) { index in
                            TextAreaView(title: questions[index], text: $homeVM.trialText)
                                .tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: Show us how you're using `ProgressBarView` in  `ContentView`. Try removing `if shouldShowIndex(index) {` what happens?

Comment: Wrong logic, nothing from SwiftUI side.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the helps,
I figured it out by NoeOnJupiter's suggestion.
I just have to remove

```
shouldShowIndex(index) {...}
```

and from the CapsuleView, I need to change "==" to "<="

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CRConstants.cornerRadius10)
            .fill( currentIndex >= index ? Color.blue : Color.clear).opacity(0.5)
```